# Golden ratio between words and pictures

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, mobile-web

In life , its about striking a balance between Y and X to achieve the best outcome.

The [Golden ratio has been applied to the web design](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/golden-ratio-in-moden-designs/) and several questions on this site has also  covered the Golden ratio but it seems no attention  has been paid to what is the **ratio of words VS pictures a website/form should have**.

I am wondering if there is any theory regarding how much percentage of your website/form should be words and how much percentage of your website should be pictures.

Answer (score 6):

**I seriously doubt there is a golden or fixed ratio of the "number of words to images" as the amount of textual content to visual content will depend on the objective and the focus of the website**. You can potentially use different golden ratios to define how the content can be arranged mentioned in this smashing magazine article

> The golden rectangle design is well suited for photo galleries,
>   portfolios and product-oriented websites. The golden rectangles can
>   also be arranged in other mathematically sound ways to generate
>   beautiful designs. In particular, you may want to use them for blocks
>   that display images or ads in your sidebar.
>
> [image]

Similarly the fibonacci series can be used for defining the content distribution as quoted in this article

> A Fibonacci design is best suited to blogs and magazine layouts. You
>   can arrange the layout in different ways according to Fibonacci
>   numbers. The article “Nombre d’or, suite de Fibonacci et autres
>   grilles de mise en page pour le design web” (in French) explains in
>   more depth the application of Fibonacci numbers to Web design. Again,
>   notice that you need to be creative when using Fibonacci sequence in
>   your designs, otherwise your designs will turn out to be too rigid and
>   hence difficult to use and navigate.

Some examples of content with different distributions of images and text are given below. **Please note all of the examples still follow the golden ratio rule but have different content distribution levels**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]